# Prove that $\{a_n\}$ is a monotonically increasing sequence and it bounded by $c$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

> For $c > 1$, define sequence $\{a_n\}$ with $a_1 = \sqrt{c(c-1)}$ and $a_{n+1} = \sqrt{c(c-1) +
> a_n}$, $n > 1$. Prove that $\{a_n\}$ is a monotonically increasing
>   sequence and it's bounded by $c$.

**My attempt:**

Obviously $a_1 < a_2$, by induction, suppose $a_n > a_{n-1}$, i.e. $a_n - a_{n-1} > 0$. We have $a_{n+1}^2 - a_n^2 = c(c-1) + a_n - c(c-1) - a_{n-1} = a_n - a_{n-1} > 0$. Hence, $\{a_n\}$ is a monotonically increasing sequence. Otherwise, $a_1 = \sqrt{c(c-1)} \leq c$ because $c^2 - a_1^2 = c^2 - c(c-1) = c \geq 0$, by induction, suppose $a_n \leq c$, we prove that $a_{n+1} \leq c$. $a_{n+1} = \sqrt{c(c-1) + a_n} < \sqrt{c(c-1) + c}$, but $c^2 - \left(\sqrt{c(c-1) + c}\right)^2 \geq 0$, then $a_{n+1} \leq c$.

Is this solution true? Thank all!

Comment: I think if $a_{n+1} > a_n$ then $a_{n+1}^2 > a_n^2$

Comment: And conversely, since the $a_i$ are positive. But what you have written is false, so correct it.

Comment: $a_1 = \sqrt{c(c-1)} > 0$ with $c>1$ and $a_1 < a_2$, so all $a_i$ are positive.

Comment: oh! I see, I was corrected it